# How to combine all rows into a single row in R?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 100 rows and 10 columns, i wonder how I can merge all the 100 rows into just one row? Thanks.

```
mydata=seq(1,1000)
mydata=as.data.frame(matrix(mydata,nrow = 100,ncol = 10,byrow=T))

the result should be like this：(just a single row)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 ……
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like? Summed, concatenated, nested vectors, or something else?

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks.

Comment: `as.data.frame(matrix(mydata, nrow = 1))`?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not the right answer.

Comment: Then perhaps you can provide some more information? My suggestion includes all of your data in a single row. (Perhaps you can present a more [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to better explain what you are expecting.)

Comment: Your answer will divide `mydata` into one row. But it includes ten variables and each of them contains 10 values. That is not what I am asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the `transpose` and concatenate to a `vector`.  Note that the `transpose` converts to a `matrix` and there is no need to call `as.matrix`.

```
as.vector(t(mydata))
```

Or we can use unlist after splitting the rows into a list.

```
unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(mydata)), function(i) mydata[i,]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Matrix are indexed by column so I am guessing you may just need to transpose your data and then construct a new matrix from it:

```
matrix(t(as.matrix(mydata)), nrow = 1)
```

Or you can convert it to a vector after the transposing depending on what you need:

```
as.vector(t(as.matrix(mydata)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  `nrow=1` will change each column into a row, you are amazing.

Comment: Thanks again. `as.vector` works too, and the core is to transpose, thanks.